# OpenVPN client internet lost when connecting OpenVPN server to another VPN while OpenVPN server has the internet

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, openvpn, openconnect

I config **OpenVPN** service on **CentOS 7** and Clients could connect to the server with no problem.
the problem occurred when OpenVPN server connect to another VPN(openconnet VPN).at this time clients lost internet while the server has internet.
I added *forwarding rule* between OpenVPN and OpenConnect in **iptables**.
`-A INPUT -s tun0 -o tun1 -j ACCET`
 
and vise verse.

what is the reason?

Comment: Did you also set up a NAT rule?

Comment: NAT for what? if you meant for Openvpn it is correct, but if meant for next Vpn please give more explanation.

Comment: A NAT rule for the traffic you're trying to forward from tun0 to tun1. It's not always required, but if openconnect is some random VPN for privacy provider, it is.

Comment: excellent, it is worked now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding [derober](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377499/openvpn-client-internet-lost-when-connecting-openvpn-server-to-another-vpn-while#comment670970_377499) comment, it correct.
`-A POSTROUTING -s OpenVpnRange -o OpenConnectNICName -j MASQERADE`